# Call function on click unless click occurs on certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user clicks on a modal, I'd like the modal to hide. I'm accomplishing this by using this code:

```
$(".modal").click(function(event){
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```

However, `.modal` contains an `img` and `p`, and when the user clicks on these elements I don't want the modal to hide. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(event.target).is('.modal')` to check if the clicked element is a modal.

```
$(".modal").on('click', function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.modal')) {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/e9o7vLz7/)

Comment: `$(event.target).hasClass('modal')` would be better than using `.is`. Well... not in ANY WAY noticeably... but just in terms of using the right tool for the job.

Comment: @GuyPassy Why exactly would it be better? I mean, both work. Would you say that `.is()` is better for checking element types?

Comment: It is *arguably* more readable. Also, as I stated, `hasClass` is a more specific tool for this type of check. `is` is a very general tool and can do many different checks, but it obfuscates more actions in the background. I find that getting used to such general implementations becomes a problem when they are used exclusively. One forgets that there are better tools for certain actions. But again, in this case, no noticeable difference. Checking element types does seem to be a good use-case for `is` - the alternative being plain javascript.